# error in digital fonts

Tags: html, css, font-face

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "digital",digital sans ef medium;
     /* Saf3+, Chrome4+, FF3.5, Opera 10+ */
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "digital",Caviar Dreams Bold;
     /* Saf3+, Chrome4+, FF3.5, Opera 10+ */
}
h1 { font-family: "digital",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:43px; line-height:37px; font-weight:normal;}

h2 { font-family: "digital",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:16px;line-height:14px; font-weight:normal;}

h3 { font-family: "digital",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:16px;line-height:14px; font-weight:normal; color:#c4161c; margin:6px 0 6px 0;}
```

I have used this css and installed true type fonts through control panel -> fonts, but still these fonts are not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to include the source and format of the font as well. For example:

```
@font-face {
font-family: digital;
src: url("path-to-the-font-file/digital.otf") format("opentype");
}
```

Comment: @font-face {
 font-family: "digital";
 src: url('digital-sans-ef-medium.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Saf3+, Chrome4+, FF3.5, Opera 10+ */
}

i have used in this way, but yet not worked

Comment: @user799100 is the font path correct? may be you can try to test some other font and see if that works?